# Using libgit2sharp with LINQPad?

Tags: linqpad, libgit2sharp

I have the LINQPad version with NuGet and I add libgit2sharp but this relies on a another (native) dll.

I've tried:

- Copying them my systemdirectory.
- Put them in a separate directory that I've added to the path.
- Put them in LINQPads plugin directory.
- Copy them when I run the query to `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

I'm just trying to read the log with this library and having it as a snippet in LINQPad would be neat though I suppose I could make it a console application if all else fails.

Anyone used libgit2sharp with LINQPad and can explain how to make them play nice together?

Comment: Is there an error from LinqPad? I'm not quite sure of what problem you are having.

Comment: Yeah, Unable to load DLL 'git2-9d9fff3' (the one I copied around in my tests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting the dll into a folder that is in your path or adding the location of your dll to your path should work (and works for me)

Perhaps your changes have not taken effect. Try closing and re-opening LinqPad or if that fails, log out and back into windows.

Comment: I feel stupid. I copied the dll to one of my path directories where I've always kept UnxUtils, sysinternals binaries etc. Just assumed LINQPad would find it if that had worked but restarting LINQPad was required. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: **LINQPad again supports LibGit2Sharp out of the box (as of LINQPad 5.10.02 - in beta at time of writing).** No workarounds are now required.

Unfortunately, this is broken again in LibGit2Sharp v0.22. This package no longer contains the native binaries in a subfolder beneath where LibGit2Sharp.dll is located in /libs. Instead, they are in a separate dependent NuGet package which relies on patching a project file. As LINQPad doesn't use project files, this fails.

You can work around this by adding an initialization method as suggested in other answers to populate the PATH variable with the native folder location. The following code will work without modification on any machine with the current LibGit2Sharp:

```
void Main()
{
   ... your query here...
}

static UserQuery()
{
   const string pathEnvVariable = "PATH";
   char slash = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
   char pathSep = Path.PathSeparator;

   // The correct native binary file is located under a folder ending in
   // "windows\x86" or "windows\amd64" or "win7-x86\native" or "win7-x64\native".
   // This may change in later LibGit2Sharp releases.
   string nativeStem1 = $"{slash}windows{slash}{(IntPtr.Size == 8 ? "amd64" : "x86")}";
   string nativeStem2 = $"{(IntPtr.Size == 8 ? "-x64" : "-x86")}{slash}native";

   // Locate the root folder in the NuGet package. This contains folders for the
   // main package (LibGit2Sharp) plus dependencies (LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries).
   var nugetRoot = new FileInfo (typeof (Repository).Assembly.Location)
      .Directory.Parent.Parent.Parent;

   var nativeBinaryPath = nugetRoot
      .GetFiles ("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
      .Single (d => d.DirectoryName.EndsWith (nativeStem1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    d.DirectoryName.EndsWith (nativeStem2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      .Directory
      .FullName;

   string currentPaths = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable (pathEnvVariable);

   if (!(pathSep + currentPaths + pathSep).ToUpperInvariant().Contains
      (pathSep + nativeBinaryPath.ToUpperInvariant() + pathSep))
   {
      Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable (pathEnvVariable, currentPaths + pathSep + nativeBinaryPath);
   }
}
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly call this method because it's in a static constructor.

Another workaround would be to publish another LibGit2Sharp package on NuGet that included the native binaries in the expected locations under where LibGit2Sharp.dll is located (NativeBinaries\x86\git2-785d8c4.dll and NativeBinaries\amd86\git2-785d8c4.dll) - download LibGit2Sharp 0.21.0.176 for an example.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  For some reason my LinqPad seems to be running the query from the `TEMP` folder.  This means it blows up with `InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element`. when getting the NuGet root.  When I change this line to this it works: `var nugetRoot = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(localAppData, "LINQPad", "NuGet.FW46"));`

Comment: Is this broken again? I'm trying to use LINQPad 5.36.03 with LibGit2Sharp 0.26 and getting `DllNotFoundException`

Comment: Yes, the latest libgit2sharp is broken for good in LINQPad 5. The workaround is to download version 0.25.4 or earlier. The good news is that it will work again in LINQPad 6 under .NET Core.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up adding the related path at runtime using:

```
void SetUpNativeBinaries(){
    var appDataLocal = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
    var packageVersion = "LibGit2Sharp.0.14.0.0";// may read from PackageInfo
    var processorArchitecture = IntPtr.Size==8?"amd64":"x86";
    var libgitNativeBinaryPath = Path.Combine(appDataLocal, "LINQPad", "NuGet", "LibGit2Sharp", packageVersion, "NativeBinaries", processorArchitecture);
    libgitNativeBinaryPath.Dump();

    var pathEnvVariable = "PATH";
    var currentPaths = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(pathEnvVariable);
    var combinedPaths = String.Format(
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0}{1}{2}",
        libgitNativeBinaryPath,
        Path.PathSeparator,
        currentPaths);

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(pathEnvVariable, combinedPaths);
}
```

Saving that as "C# Program" you can start right away:

```
void Main()
{
    SetUpNativeBinaries();
    var repoWorkingDir = @"C:\temp\libgit2_repo";
    var repo = new Repository(repoWorkingDir);

    repo.Config.Dump();
    repo.Branches.Dump();
    repo.Index.RetrieveStatus().Dump();
    //...
}
```

**Update**
[There is a closed issue and the fix is shipped with since release 0.14.1.0](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/515)

Answer (score 3):

The amazing @mbx stood up and **[helped us make this happen](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/515)**.

Thanks to him, the next release of LibGit2Sharp NuGet package (**v0.15.0**) will directly work from within LinqPad.

#### Update:

LibGit2Sharp NuGet **v0.14.1** package contain this fix and is now **[available for download](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp/0.14.1.0)**.

Comment: Version 0.22.0 of the LibGit2Sharp NuGet package isn't working in version 5.08.01 of LINQPad.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the NuGet package as-is nor [mbx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867945/173497) worked for me for version 0.22.0 of the LibGit2Sharp NuGet package and version 5.08.01 of LINQPad.

I modified the method in mbx's answer to be the following:

```
void SetUpLibGit2SharpNativeBinaries()
{
    string libGit2SharpNativeBinariesPath = @"C:\Users\kevitt\AppData\Local\LINQPad\NuGet.FW46\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries.1.0.129\libgit2\windows\x86";

    string pathEnvVariable = "PATH";
    string currentPaths = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(pathEnvVariable);

    IEnumerable<string> paths = currentPaths.Split(';');

    if (!paths.Contains(libGit2SharpNativeBinariesPath))
    {
        var combinedPaths = String.Format(
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}{1}{2}",
            libGit2SharpNativeBinariesPath,
            Path.PathSeparator,
            currentPaths);

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(pathEnvVariable, combinedPaths);
    }
}
```

Note that this almost certainly won't work for anyone else as-is as you'll need to replace my Windows login name with your own at minimum in the value assigned to the string variable `libGit2SharpNativeBinariesPath`.

Also, `libGit2SharpNativeBinariesPath` (corresponding to the `libgitNativeBinaryPath` string in mbx's code) didn't seem to now be something that could be (easily) generated as in mbx's code so you may need to determine the path yourself.

Comment: Replacing `C:\Users\kevitt\AppData\Local` with `%LOCALAPPDATA%` should make the script more generic.  You'll still be hard coded onto a fixed version of `LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries` though.  I just added `%LOCALAPPDATA%\LINQPad\NuGet.FW46\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries.1.0.129\libgit2\windows\x86` to my `PATH` and that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @KevinKuszyk I actually tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. Mind trying it yourself?

Comment: So now I'm confused.  This worked last week, but it's broken again today.  I'll investigate some more and post an update when I have one.

Comment: I'm making progress.  It seems `%LOCALAPPDATA%` doesn't work in LinqPad, but `var localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` does.

Comment: @KevinKuszyk As Joe Albahari mentioned in [his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983085/using-libgit2sharp-with-linqpad/39883504?noredirect=1#comment67195312_39940985) to you on his answer this question, he's going to 'fix' this in LINQPad; more details [here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1370#issuecomment-252554602).

Comment: Yes, I saw that this morning.  I've added Joe's workaround to our scripts. I'll take it out when the new version of LinqPad ships.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:  copy git2-785d8c4.dll into the same directory as LibGit2Sharp.dll and restart LINQPad.

```
copy %LOCALAPPDATA%\LINQPad\NuGet.FW46\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries.2.0.267\runtimes\win-x86\native\git2-785d8c4.dll %LOCALAPPDATA%\LINQPad\NuGet.FW46\LibGit2Sharp\LibGit2Sharp.0.26.0\lib\net46
```

(LibGit2Sharp.0.26.0, LINQPad 5.36.03)